# inter-EU migration 2015 Data source request

Tags: data-request, migration

I need inter-EU migration data for the year 2015 for validating a model.

I want to build a matrix A indexed by EU countries where A[i,j] is the migration of citizens of country *j* to country *i*.

I looked at the Eurostat page [Migration and migrant population statistics](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Migration_and_migrant_population_statistics)  but could not find what I want.

Comment: 20x28: https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIG Screenshot: https://screenshots.firefox.com/bh0m4cAEf8ZZneuT/stats.oecd.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background**

- Worldbank [provides](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/migrationremittancesdiasporaissues/brief/migration-remittances-data) detailed data on bilateral migration only up to 2013;
- Eurostat [provides](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=migr_imm1ctz&lang=en) data broken down by broad groups of citizenship only.

**Partial answer**

Some members of EU are also members of OECD. OECD [provides](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIG) data up to 2015.

In the default view of "International Migration Database":

1. choose *Customize > Layout* and reverse "Year" and "Country of birth";
2. click on column names and select appropriate values. The table will look like this:

[image: OECD migration database]

3. choose *Export > Excel* or *Export > CSV*.

**Methodology**

- OECD distinguishes countries of citizenship, of birth,
  and of previous residence;
- Nevertheless, different countries count migrants
  [differently](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/en/migr_immi_esms.htm).

**Missing part**

According to [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FcountryLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ185441%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP463%20wd%3AQ41550%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D), these EU members are not members of OECD:

- Kingdom of the Netherlands
- Lithuania
- Romania
- Bulgaria
- Croatia
- Cyprus
- Malta

Probably you could find missing data visiting:

- [EU national statistical offices](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/links);
- [EU data portals](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/organization).

**See also**

This article looks interesting (contains some theory):

- [Migration Systems in Europe: Evidence From Harmonized Flow Data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4098031/) (2012).